# Can Java atomically modify TWO or MORE objects?

Tags: java, concurrency

Is there a way to modify atomically two or more objects in Java?

For example, atomically set two fields of an object.

UPDATED

I have removed all questions except for the last one due to the rules of the community.

Comment: Is this homework? Did you try answering these questions yourself?

Comment: You have asked 4 questions as one posted question. Please ask 4 questions as 4 separate questions.

Comment: I don't quite understand the 4. question. You can do whatever you like within a `synchronized` block. It's up to you, how many fields you set within the scope. Or are you talking about `AtomicReference`, `AtomicInteger`, etc.? What's meant with atomic here?

Comment: Dirk, synchronized scope doesnt make the operations atomic. I mean can we call something like this: compareAndSet(Object1, Object2, expected1,expected2,newValue1,newValue2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to number 1: No, this is not thread-safe publication. Consider the following interleaving of events:

```
t1:                   t2:
a = new A();
                      a.getSomeField();
a.setSomeField(1);
```

in other words, `t2` is able to see a partially constructed object, and the value of `someField` is undefined by the time it is read by `t2`. Technically, the value, t2 will receive, is undefined, and if you are (un-) lucky, `t2` will simply see the default value (in case of an `int` field usually 0).

For number 2: both threads need to synchronize on the same object, otherwise you can omit the synchronization completely (as it would have the same effect).

Number 3: yes, this is guaranteed by the JVM. All waiting threads will be awaken, and they all will try to grab the lock (again) before they can make progress (and of course, only one can succeed at this, and all other threads will have to implicitly wait -- on the lock, this time, not on the condition variable).

Number 4: There is no "multi-place" `compareAndSet`. If I need something like this, I usually do it with a tiny helper class:

```
class State {
    final int field1;
    final String field2;
    State(int f1, String f2) {
        this.field1 = f1;
        this.field2 = f2;
    }
    State derive(int arg1) {
        ...
    }
}

private final AtomicReference<State> state = new AtomicReference<>(new State(0, ""));

public void changeState(int whatever) {

    for (;;) {
        final State s = state.get();
        final State t = s.derive(whatever);
        if (state.compareAndSet(s, t)) return;
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand t2 cannot see a partially constructed object if it is provided by volatile marked reference.

Comment: As for the order - lets assume that t2 always runs after t1. Does volatile modifier ensures the visibility of all fields of the object and we dont need to make someField volatile too?

Comment: @Dymytry - With partially constructed I refer to `someField` not being properly initialized (wrt to the missing call to `setSomeField`, not to what the constructor of `A` may have done). The `volatile` declaration on `a` doesn't somehow automatically ensure, that `a = new A()` and `a.setSomeField(1)` occur in some magic atomic "transaction".